# Unable to display the data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to display the data onselect method but the data is not getting displayed.
This is the code.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
    alert(str);
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select a person:</option>
        <option value="1">MEGHALI</option>
        <option value="2">SONY</option>
        <option value="3">DHANU</option>
        <option value="4">ADITYA</option>
        <option value="5">MAHESH</option>
        <option value="6">NEERAJ</option>
        <option value="7">VINEET</option>
        <option value="8">ASHWINI</option>
        <option value="9">SANTOSH</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the getuser.php

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", " ", "flowers");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"FLOWERS");
$sql="SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>CITY</th>
<th>PHONE</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CITY'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PHONE'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I guess the `getuser.php?q="+str` is not getting passed.
Please help as I am newbie to ajax.

Comment: What is your database name? FLOWERS or flowers?

Comment: Please narrow down your problem. If you don't even know yet whether it's the database connection/query that fails or the AJAX request, there's no reason yet to ask this question here.

Comment: Simplify by using j query instead [Click here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

if you are passing id in getuser.php like:

> getuser.php?q=1

you should get passed parameter like :

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

and query the database

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE id = '".$q."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply passing doesn't get the variable there you need to get it by

```
$q=$_GET['q'];
```

in your query page.
and try again. if still it is not working try echoing your mysql query and check whether you are getting the value of $q there.